# How to setup junit to run with aspectJ

Tags: junit, aspectj

I want to run junit test and at the same time want to log the trace in a file using aspectJ in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the AspectJ in Action book (2nd edition), it's covered in Chapter 10.

You'll need to create an Aspect (.aj) file in Eclipse, call it whatever (maybe TraceAspect).

You'll then need to define (1) pointcut:

```
pointcut trace() : execution (* *.*(..)) && (!within(TraceAspect))
```

Then define a method such as before()/around()/execution()/call()

```
before() : trace() {
    Signature sign = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    // Do stuff
}
```

Some other examples would be:

http://code.google.com/p/springside/source/browse/springside3/trunk/examples/showcase/src/main/java/org/springside/examples/showcase/log/trace/TraceAspect.java?r=1105

http://code.google.com/p/dremel/source/browse/src/dremel/common/loggingaspect/TraceAspect.aj?repo=metaxa&r=bb10a0d0a9e82d3fe6bb2b39e0f3a44d7ceafc4b